# Oracle Database installation error: environment path

Tags: oracle11g, installation, environment-variables, rdbms, system-variable

While attempting to install **Oracle Database 11g Release 2** on **Windows 7 (64 bit)**.

Encountered following the error (**PRVF-3929**)

[image: oracle install wizard]

It states that the environment variable path is too long. To reach this variable I searched "envir"  in Windows and selected "Edit variable settings for your account". Presumably it's the path of the system rather than user that must be changed.

[image: system]

Can I delete at my discretion - naturally removing extensions will have a bearing on different language compilations. Why does Oracle demand this limit and is this specific to the install of Oracle or is it a permanent limitations of using oracle dbms?

Comment: Pls refer to this link with same issues
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089655/how-to-install-oracle-11g-client

Comment: @HolaAmigos the other link also did not address why the Oracle environment variable is not there to begin with. How does the variable get entered the first time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *limitation is based on older Windows restrictions*, where length of environmental variables was important. This limitation is still there in the Oracle installation.

***Work around this:***

- Step 1: Copy the value of your 'path' variable to a text-editor (Ex.: notepad) and save this value as backup.
- Step 2: **Reduce the size** of this path to less that 1023 characters. Remove path variables at the end. You will mostly not need any of them during the oracle installation. Keep those removed values in a separate text-file, because you need to add them again later!
- Step 3: **Start the oracle installation** again.
- Step 4: After Oracle installation: **Add those removed path values again** at the end of the path.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for "Start the oracle installation again". The rest I had tried but this eluded me