# Error in installing Oracle database on Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, windows-7-x64

I have windows 7 professional and I am trying to install Oracle database 11g release 2 I am getting this error every timer  :
**the length of the environment variable "PATH" does not exceed the recommended length**.

- how can i solve this problem? i need your help.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089655/oracle-client-installation-error-path-too-long

Comment: but it's not worked for me

Comment: "*how can i solve this problem?*" - make your `PATH` shorter. Many programs add themselves to the `PATH` but those entries aren't actually needed.

Comment: unfortunately but it's not worked for me